# C function is returning 0 even though debugger shows it returning 1

Tags: c, embedded, msp430

I am writing embedded C code for an MSP430 microcontroller, and I have gotten stuck on a function returning an incorrect value. When I step through the code with debugger, it shows the function should return 1, but it is returning 0 on the int that is set.

Code:

```
void sendUart(unsigned char string[], int length){
    if(string != 0){
        while(~responseAOK()){
            int BLEstatus = BLEReadyForData();  **//Function called here**

            if(BLEstatus){  **//At this point, BLEstatus is 0 (incorrect)
                unsigned int i;
                for(i=0;i<length-1;i++){
                    while(!(IFG2 & UCA0TXIFG)); 
                    UCA0TXBUF = string[i];  
                    send[sendIndex] = string[i];
                    sendIndex++;
                }
                sendIndex = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}

int BLEReadyForData(){
    if(P2DIR & BIT3){     
        P2DIR &= ~BIT3;         
    }

    if(P2IN & BIT3){ 
        return 1;  //debugger step-through reaches this line of code
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are P2DIR and BIT3 initialized/set? Which debugger? Usually if I see different output from the debugger and the actual program, I think it might be an initialization problem (where the debugger happens to treat something uninitialized as NULL). Depending on your debugger, you can probably force it to use 0xAA (or something) for uninitialized blocks.

Comment: Is either P2IN or BIT3 a memory mapped register? And if so, can reading the register change its value? Otherwise, is there more than one thread touching these variables?

Comment: The debugger is part of Code Composer Studio (made by Texas Instruments for their boards). All those variables (P2DIR, BIT3, P2IN) and predefined in the provided library for the board, in msp430.h.

Comment: MichaelVeksler They are registers, and they don't change by reading them.

Comment: @DonPiano so they are memory mapped register. They reflect some state of hardware, so they might spontaneously change over time

Comment: My bet is that the debugger just isn't perfectly reflecting the execution of the code. For example, the compiler may have optimized the `return 1;` and the `return 0;` into a single internal statement, kind of like `int a = (P2IN & BIT3) != 0; return a;` and so it is showing that you are on  that consolidated internal statement by showing you one of the lines of C code that corresponds to it. That can be a significant optimization because it eliminates a flow control statement (conditional branch) which is expensive on some CPUs.

Comment: Can you show the assembly for BLEReadyForData? It should be very small

Comment: You are all correct. I am just looking at the register list now and the one i'm polling is 0. I did not know I could view the value of the register like that until now. Thanks!

Comment: I guess part of the problem was that I don't know if the CTS and RTS on the bluetooth chip mean that the BLE chip is ready to send (output) or if it is an input for the mcu to set.

Comment: Registers *can* change by reading them, particularly a status bit. I don't know about *this* register but that is an incorrect sweeping statement. Also, you are working with UART and checking "ready for data". Using a debugger may affect the timing, because at a break point the character transmission might not have completed, but when the register is examined, it has.

Comment: Coution when reading hardware registers in a debugger, because as @WeatherVane says, they can change by virtue of being read - including being read by the debugger.  The result is that your code may behave incorrectly exactly because you are using a debugger!  In addition be sure you are not applying _any_ optimisations.  If the code still appears to be doing something incorrect, switch to assembler-view and step that to determine exactly what decisions are being made and in what values.

Comment: Also, generally GPIO registers require a bit of a delay from setting data direction until the point where the change goes live on the I/O pins. Make sure that this isn't the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should turn off optimization first. It makes step-through debugging confusing.
For example, in IAR it's

```
Project -> Options -> C/C++ Compiler -> Optimizations tab -> Level -> None
```